# API authentication from a facebook messenger bot conversation

Tags: facebook, authentication, bots, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

What is the best way to authenticate with an external API from a conversation with a bot on the facebook messenger platform?

For a broad example, I would like a user of my bot to create items on their own profiles of an external website. Is there a way to get login information from the user, or connect my bot to the external website, without the user explicitly sending a message to the bot with their username and password?

What I found in the documentation under [User Profile API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference#user_profile_request):

> You can personalize the conversation using the person's name or profile pic from the User Profile API. In order to get this information, make a GET request to https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/?fields=first_name,last_name,profile_pic&access_token=. Read more details in the Send API reference.

This isn't quite what I'm looking for but it helps. Here's more info from the docs:

> User Profile API
>
> Request
>
> `curl -X GET "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/<USER_ID>?fields=first_name,last_name,profile_pic&access_token=<PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN>"`
>
> Response
>
> `{
>     "first_name": "Peter",
>     "last_name": "Chang",
>     "profile_pic": "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile...70ec9c19b18"
>   }`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It depends how they come in.

1. If they come from your website, you can use the Send to Messengee button from within their account. Use the pass through param to link your account to the user thread.
   Here's an excerpt from the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/implementation):

> The plugin takes in a pass-through parameter defined by you. This parameter is sent back to you via a callback. You can use this to link the authentication event to a person and/or transaction. For example, a person may enter an online flow for a specific transaction and click the Send-to-Messenger button. You can pass in data to know which user and transaction was tied to the authentication event. You should encode and encrypt this parameter.

2. If they come directly to your bot, you would have to present them with a login of some sort (your login) from within the conversation. This would happen in a link to an mobile web URLs.

Comment: this is pretty much what I was looking for, thanks! I'm going to edit your answer to include more details from the documentation.

Comment: @pschang what if i want to implement third party Oauth flow in bot like getting user's access token of his twiiter account what should be the best practice ? as if user provide his twitter username,password that will be not a good practice...any idea ?

Comment: @ANinJa I need the same solution, have you managed to figure it out ? :)

Comment: @VaclovasRekašiusJr. what kind of use case you are implementing ?

Comment: @ANinJa I'd like to implement facebook login through messenger generic message ( lets say a simple button).