# Implement third party OAuth flow in Facebook messenger bot

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth, oauth-2.0, facebook-messenger-bot

Is there any way we can we implement the "Authorization code grant" flow of OAuth 2.0 in a facebook messenger bot ?

I see a query by @ANinJa related to this in the comments section, but couldn't find any answers

[API authentication from a facebook messenger bot conversation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36603291/api-authentication-from-a-facebook-messenger-bot-conversation)

I need to authenticate the users with an external IAM providers and I need to pass the id token and access token to the webhook.

Regards,
Albie Morken

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/account-linking/v2.10

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I am trying to do the same thing with a FB Messenger bot but through DialogFlow. I got to the point where my API returns the Authrization URI which opens in the browser and the user has to log in...but after the login, how do I go right back to the bot? Right now the user has to close the browser window and say something to the bot to initiate the next step. Any help would be great!

Comment: Once the login is successful, you get the notification to your registered oauth callback. From there you can POST to your Facebook web hook code and from there you can send message to the face book bot.